# Objective-C: Search Array

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I was looking for some help with my code. Every time I enter in any word it comes up as "Sweet!"

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong!

```
-(IBAction)enter:(id)sender{

    word = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@", display1.text, display2.text, display3.text, display4.text, display5.text, display6.text, display7.text, display8.text, display9.text];

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dict" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if (error)
        NSLog(@"Error reading file: %@", error.localizedDescription);

    NSArray *dictionary= [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"/n"];

    BOOL isTheWordThere = [dictionary indexOfObject:word];

    if((isTheWordThere = YES)){
        display.text = @"Sweet!";
    }
    else if ((isTheWordThere = NO)){
        display.text = @"Woops";
    }
}
```

Please excuse my code for beginners

The `Dictionary` array is simply a list of about 100,000 words.

Comment: `indexOfObject` return an `NSUInteger`. If the word isn't at index zero, then, it would be "YES", since "0 == NO".

Comment: Write a simpler test, make `word` a literal string.

Comment: Also you have used wrong slash. Use "\\n" to separate out your components.

Comment: And `isTheWordThere = YES` is an *assignment*, not a *comparison*.

Comment: And why do you call an array variable "dictionary" ?? - Btw. did you try to **debug** your problem?

Comment: that code screams "kill me... kill meee...." clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `indexOfObject` returns an integer and `NSNotFound` if the word is not found.

Better code:

```
NSUInteger wordIndex = [dictionary indexOfObject:word];
BOOL isTheWordThere = wordIndex != NSNotFound;
if (isTheWordThere) {
    your code here
```

Also:
Do not test `error`, test `fileContents` for nil. `error` may be set to some value even if there is no error.

As @Apurv comments: The line separator is incorrect, it should be `\n`.

As @Martin comments: in the equality test you have `=` which is assignment, you need `==` which is equality.

As @Martin comments: Name things well, an array should not be named `dictionary` find a more descriptive name, perhaps something like `wordList`.

Here is a simple test case, you can change the test line to either `wordList1` or `wordList2` to test both cases"

```
NSString *word = @"test";
NSArray *wordList1 = @[@"word", @"test", @"another"];
NSArray *wordList2 = @[@"word", @"bad",  @"another"];

NSUInteger wordIndex = [wordList2 indexOfObject:word];
NSLog(@"wordIndex: %lu", wordIndex);

BOOL isTheWordThere = (wordIndex != NSNotFound);

NSString *text;
if(isTheWordThere == YES) {
    text = @"Sweet!";
}
else {
    text = @"Woops";
}
NSLog(@"text: %@", text);
```

The key is to create a short enough test that there is only one error at most. If there are multiple errors the change of fixing the code is really small. In your case there are at least five errors.

Then start adding in the separating a string into an array, reading the word string, creating the test word from components. One step at a time, get each working then go on the the next. Use NSLog statements and the Xcode LLDB debugger to follow exactly what is happening.

Lastly, really spend time reviewing your code. It is quick to click "run" but first really check your code. In the "old days" we only got one or two chances a day to try a compile/run so we spend a lot of time getting the code right first. Today we don't have that constraint but we should really review our code well.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! But when i use your code it seems to only show up as 'Woops'! Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Hey man, still having problems so printed wordIndex to see what the value was when I typed in a word on the list, and what it was when a word wasn't on the list. I got the same result! How will i fix this?

Comment: 1) You need to provide more information, what were the indexes? 2) Assume the Apple methods all work correctly, if they didn't the whole iOS device wouldn't work. 3) `NSNotFound is going to print as one of these: -1, 2147483647 or bigger on 64 bit systems.

Answer (score 0):

Your line `BOOL isTheWordThere = [dictionary indexOfObject:word];` is wrong.

If your word doesn't exist, the given index will be `-1`
And since `-1` is not equal to `0`, the value of `isTheWordThere` is `YES`.

Moreover, if you want to test `isTheWordThere` you should write `==` instead of `=` !